# OpenGL what is happening with the colours?

Tags: c, opengl

I can not understand what is happening when I change from one colour to another one due to the fact that in the bottom of the picture seems distorted

Photo:

[image]

Comment: Don't post images if text! Post text as text!

Answer (score 4):

1. You are calling `glClear` between `glBegin` and `glEnd`. You are not permitted to do that. Besides, I don't understand why would you want to clear the color buffer right after you drew a primitive into it.
2. You use `glBegin(GL_POLYGON)`: **GL_POLYGON** means that all those vertices you pass are assembled into one huge polygon with self-intersections. Instead you should use`glBegin(GL_QUADS)` to draw multiple rectangles.